# Why does my client keep recieving b'' and my server crashes

Tags: python-3.x

So, I'm trying to learn to properly use sockets in python 3.2.5, I found an example of a basic client and server on the internet and edited it a bit to work with python 3.x (shown here):
Server:

```
print("Server")
from socket import *
myHost = ''
myPort = 2000
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)    # create a TCP socket
s.bind((myHost, myPort))            # bind it to the server port
s.listen(5)                         # allow 5 connections
while 1:
    # wait for next client to connect
    connection, address = s.accept() # connection is a new socket
    while 1:
        data = connection.recv(1024) # receive up to 1K bytes
        if data:
            connection.send('echo -> ' + data.decode("UTF-8"))
        else:
            break
    connection.close()              # close socket
```

Client:

```
print("Client")
import sys
from socket import *
serverHost = 'localhost'            # servername is localhost
serverPort = 2000                   # use arbitrary port > 1024

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)    # create a TCP socket


s.connect((serverHost, serverPort)) # connect to server on the port
s.send(bytes("Hi", "UTF-8"))        # send the data
while 1:
    data = s.recv(1024)             # receive up to 1KB
    print(data)
```

However, my client will infinitely recieve and print "b''", even when the server isn't running. (The infinite loop may be unnecesary and is just there are an example.) I was wondering why this was.

Another problem I'm having with it is that the server will crash as soon as the client launches and sends it a message, it gives this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\server.py", line 14, in <module>
    connection.send('echo -> ' + data.decode("UTF-8"))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the server fails is that;

```
connection.send('echo -> ' + data.decode("UTF-8"))
```

...attempts to send a string, but `send` wants a byte array. In other words, you need to do something similar to;

```
connection.send(bytes('echo -> ' + data.decode("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"))
```

At the client side, you're not taking into account that the socket may be closed from the server side where by `recv` will return 0 bytes. Your while loop would be better off breaking on an empty array;

```
while 1:
    data = s.recv(1024)             # receive up to 1KB
    if len(data) == 0:              # but stop if socket is closed
        break
    print(data)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, didn't answer the question about the b'' and what that means, but the quotes contain the message anyway and I can work with it. Thanks!

Comment: @Shimshar `b''` is a byte array containing nothing (ie how a 0 byte byte array is displayed).